# Dynamic state city drop down list in mvc using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am adding values to  2 dropdownlists dynamically ,to the state dropdownlist it is populated during form load and to the city it must be populated when the jquery fires out when the user clicks on any state,the problem i am facing is that,the state dropdownlist is easily populated  but the city dropdownlist does not contain any values when i select a particular state,
the state and city are strings stored in a table in my db
i ll post my code below so that if anyone can sort out what is wrong with my code

**homecontroller**

```
 public ActionResult registration()
        {
            ViewBag.states = dd.tb_statecities.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text=m.state}).Distinct().ToList();


            return View();

        }
        public ActionResult get(string state)
        {


            var v = (dd.tb_statecities.Where(m => m.state == state).Select(m => m.city)).ToList();
            return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

**jquery..**

```
$(function () {

    $('#states').change(function () {

        var val = $('#states').val();
        $.get("home/get", { state: val }, function (data) {
            var v = "<option>Select</option>"
            $.each(data, function (i, q) {
                alert("hello");
                v += "<option value=" + q + ">" + q + "</option>";


            });
            $('#city').html(v);

        });

    });

});
```

**registration.cshtml**

State @Html.DropDownList("states","Select")

```
    </tr>
     <tr class="t">
        <td>City</td>



          <td>@Html.DropDownList("city", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{Text="Select",Value="0"}})</td>

    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't send value/id when you use ViewBag,
I suggest you use SelectList in your ViewBag :

```
ViewBag.states = new SelectList(db.states, "ID", "states");
```

Then you can get the value from using JQuery :

```
var val = $('#states').val();
```